# Tensor model input - nvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape in shape_and_slice spec

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Hey I am trying to set an input point for the model that i have writen in tensorflow 
this is the code for the classification

```
n_dim = training_features.shape[1]
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_dim])

classifier = (...)
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    classifier.fit(training_features, training_labels, steps=100)
    accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(testing_features, testing_labels, steps=100)["accuracy"]
    print('Accuracy', accuracy_score)

    pred_a = np.asarray([x])
    prediction = format(list(classifier.predict(pred_a)))
    prediction_result = np.array(prediction)
    output = tf.convert_to_tensor(prediction_result,dtype=None,name="output", preferred_dtype=None)
```

and here is my building code

```
export_path_base = sys.argv[-1]
export_path = os.path.join(
    compat.as_bytes(export_path_base),
    compat.as_bytes(str(FLAGS.model_version)))
print('Exporting trained model to', export_path)
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

classification_inputs = utils.build_tensor_info(y)
classification_outputs_classes = utils.build_tensor_info(output)

print('classification_signature...')
classification_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS: classification_inputs},
    outputs={
        signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
            classification_outputs_classes
    },
    method_name=signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME)
tensor_info_x = utils.build_tensor_info(x)

print('prediction_signature...')
prediction_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={'input': tensor_info_x},
    outputs={
        'classes' : classification_outputs_classes
    },
    method_name=signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME)
print('Exporting...')
legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
        'predict_sound':
            prediction_signature,
        signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
            classification_signature,
    },
    legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)
builder.save()
print('Saved...')
```

I have tried manually passing dummy data before the build and that works but i am trying to have the client stub pass data into the model dynamically. 
When i try run that code to build i get this error

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape in
>   shape_and_slice spec [1,280] does not match the shape stored in
>   checkpoint: [193,280]      [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 =
>   RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]

May main goal is to have x as an input and output return the results, the output works but cant get the input to work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If you just put the np.array as input without going through an input function, it will work but you also give up the chance to check the input.

Tensorflow won't check your input even if it's in the wrong shape or type or somehow corrupted but to throw such an error in the middle of session. Since you can run it with your test data successfully, the problem should be your actual data. Thus, it's recommended to write an input function to check your data before put it into classifier. Note that input function should return tf.Tensor with the shape of [x,1] (x is the number of your features) instead of an np.array.

Please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn to see how to write your own input function and pass it to the classifier.

An example of input function:

```
def input_fn_predict(): # returns x, None
    #do your check here or you can just print it out
    feature_tensor = tf.constant(pred_a,shape=[1,pred_a.size])
    return feature_tensor,None
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16060019)

Comment: I think I have made myself clear that the error is caused because he passed an np.array to a function that needs tf.Tensor as input, which directly answered his question.

Comment: hey @QinHeyang if you mean the point i passed an array to the prediction then your solution wouldn't work as it does not accept tensors as input.

Comment: @QinHeyang The key word here is your first word "Probably" - it indicates that you didn't really know if that was the answer when you wrote the answer. I recommend not using the word "probably" if you really mean to make a definitive answer.

Comment: hey @QinHeyang thanks for this, I now understand the input functions and have used that in stead of converting to the numpy arrays.

Comment: @QinHeyang My Question is(and maybe I am not very clear), during serving i have to define what tensor will be used for inputs (at run time), how will i be able to define this tensor?

Comment: @BrianPhiri You can just return the tensor you want in your input function. I add an example in the answer which returns pred_a in your code.